# detect API version through sfinae

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I work on a code base where the C++ API is about to change (master branch and feature branch) and I want to protect my code against the change, such that my code builds against both versions. As minimum working example [godbolt/compiler-explorer link](https://godbolt.org/g/wMjyV3):

common:

```
class SmallWidget {
 private:
  int m_i;

 public:
  int i() { return m_i; }
};
```

master:

```
class BigWidget {
 private:
  std::vector<SmallWidget*> m_v;

 public:
  auto& widgets() { return m_v; }
};
```

feature branch:

```
class BigWidget {
 private:
  std::vector<SmallWidget> m_v;

 public:
  auto& widgets() { return m_v; }
};
/**/
```

For the master version I have some call code:

```
int single_op(BigWidget& w) {
  return (*w.widgets().begin())->i(); // asterisk will need to go
}


std::vector<int> do_stuff(std::vector<BigWidget> inputs) {
  std::vector<int> retval;
  for (auto w : inputs) {
    retval.push_back(single_op(w));
  }

  return retval;
}
```

The API does not come with a preprocessor variable to select with

```
#if WIDGET_VERSION == OLD
  return (*w.widgets().begin())->i(); // asterisk will need to go
#else
  return (w.widgets().begin())->i(); // asterisk gone
#endif
```

I was trying to detect the return type of `widgets` with sfinae:

```
// version for the master branch API
template <typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<
              std::remove_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(**(
                  std::declval<BigWidget>().widgets().begin()))>::type>::type,
              SmallWidget>::value>::type>
int single_op(BigWidget& w) {
  return (*w.widgets().begin())->i();
}

// version for the feature branch API
template <typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<
              std::remove_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(*(
                  std::declval<BigWidget>().widgets().begin()))>::type>::type,
              SmallWidget>::value>::type>
int single_op(BigWidget& w) { return w.widgets().begin()->i(); }
```

But the compilers are not happy about that. clang says:

```
<source>:43:46: error: failed requirement 'std::is_same<std::remove_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(* (std::declval<BigWidget>().widgets().begin()))>::type>::type, SmallWidget>::value'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration
```

template

Is there a way to use sfinae to enable the right code here?

I also tried using `std::enable_if` for the return code or function arguments, but my understanding is that the compiler always sees the signature `int single_op(BigWidget&)` for both versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a small helper function that will take either type and return the type you want.

```
SmallWidget &getWidget(SmallWidget *w) { return *w; }
SmallWidget &getWidget(SmallWidget &w) { return w; }

int single_op(BigWidget &w) {
    return getWidget(*w.widgets().begin()).i();
}
```

You can also provide overloads for `const` versions.

Answer (score 0):

I could come up with [this](https://godbolt.org/g/AHV2Ky) version:

```
// version for the feature branch API
template <typename bigtype>
int single_op(
     typename std::enable_if<
         std::is_same<
             std::remove_const<std::remove_reference<decltype(
                *(std::declval<BigWidget>().widgets().begin()))>::type>::type,
            SmallWidget>::value,
        bigtype>::type& w) {
  return w.widgets().begin()->i();
}
```

I added one additional template argument for the BigWidget type (despite being known) and use it for the function argument of `single_op`. Now the compiler can go through both template definitions, arrive with one possible solution for the overload set and disables the unused code.

As drawback, I now have to spell out the template argument on the call side

```
retval.push_back(single_op<decltype(w)>(w));
```

But I suspect there are better solutions out there.